# Camel: Produce results to a URI that may or may not have consumer

Tags: java, events, apache-camel

I'm looking to use Camel as an in process broker of sorts.  I want to have my producer send its results to a URI, and then if there is anything at that point in time which is ready to consume, let it take them.

My produced results are valid for a short time, and the newest result is the only thing that matters up to that point in time.

Is there any camel configuration that suits this?

Answer (score 0):

your producer could send data to a JMS Topic or even just a file or database record...then a consumer could come and go to retrieve the latest data as needed...I'd favor JMS for the ease of use and flexibility